# colorbar upside down (highest values at bottom) in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

For a project I need a scatter plot w/ a colorbar in which the lowest values are at the top and the highest ones are at the bottom of the colorbar.
I could not find information on how to do this in the Manual or the www.

How can the colorbar be reversed?

The below example should, accordingly, have the 0 at the top.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colorbar]
        \addplot [only marks, scatter, scatter src={mod(\coordindex,15)}, samples=15] {rand};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the style `y dir=reverse`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colorbar, colorbar style={y dir=reverse}]
        \addplot [only marks, scatter, scatter src={mod(\coordindex,15)}, samples=15] {rand};        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]